# Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs

Node.js, Webpack

In this project using webpack, where installed FS.
This code need to read file, but returns error "Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function"

```
const bookForm = document.querySelector(".book-form"); 
const select = document.querySelector(".select"); const fs = require("fs");

export function abc() {   bookForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
    e.preventDefault();
fs.readFile("file.txt", function(error, data) {
    console.log("file read");
    if (error) throw error; 
    console.log(data);  });
    }); }
```

Comment: Is that Node.js or the browser?

Comment: yes, there is front-end project collected in webpack (sorry if some grammar faults)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import the `fs` module in the browser, because the browser environment does not have access to the user's file system. `fs` is only available in the Node.js context (on the server) but not on the client (browser).

If you want to send files from the browser to the server, you can use `<input type="file">` and let the user manually select the files they have to send. If you want to send a server file's contents to the browser, you can use HTTP communication (AJAX) or you can render it's content in a server-side computed HTML template.

Comment: thank you, but, i want just to take some info from form input and put it to txt file. What should I do?

Comment: You should make an HTML form and submit it via the browser, then on the server (Node.js) you have to handle the incoming data and save it as a text file. You can use a web-framework like Express which has most of that functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Within your config file you can set the way in which assests like your txt file is uploaded. Then you simply use require('file.txt') to load it - no need to use fs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).